# JDBC: best way to update a table?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, sql-update, resultset

Let's say that I get a ResultSet which was queryed using joins from an sql database.

Is it better to use an sql statement to update the tables or insert new tuples/rows?

Or should i use the resultSet.update() function?

I just want to know the drawbacks associated with each as well as the preferred method of updating tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ResultSet](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) will only be updatable if:

1. You've created your statement with appropriate flag (ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE)
2. The underlying database / driver supports updates over join results

If both conditions are true, updates are likely to be more efficient when done this way as you're already holding a cursor to the item. Otherwise you'll need to create a new statement - be sure to use a PreparedStatement for that.

Comment: why use a prepared statement?

Comment: Because prepared statements should pretty much always be used in place of regular ones - they can be cached / reused by the database resulting in better performance and they protect you from SQL injection attacks among other things.

Comment: + 1 - Yeah, baby.  PreparedStatement is the only way to go.  I'd be hard-pressed to think of a good reason NOT to use them.